# Loading and dumping hex values with OrderedDict

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm using the OrderedLoader from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21912744/1545653) answer. It's working great keeping the order of the file but my YAMLs have some hex fields, like:

```
  fieldA:
   subA: foo
   subB: 0xff00
   subC: 0x00aa
```

that are being converted into int fields at load time:

```
 ('fieldA', OrderedDict([('subA', 'foo'), ('subB', 65280), ('subC', 170)
```

and then dumped like:

```
fieldA:
  subA: foo
  subB: 65280
  subC: 170
```

does anybody how I can prevent this from happening? I've been dealing for a while with safe_dump BaseLoader and so on with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you do `od['subB'] = hex(od['subB'])`?  Does the output become a single-quoted string?  (`od` is a reference to your `OrderedDict`.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, if I do that then the right value is displayed. MY initial fix for this is to run a loop over all the items and covert them back to the "right" format, but I'd rather to look for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up by enclosing the hex numbers with quotes in the original YAML file:

```
  fieldA:
   subA: foo
   subB: '0xff00'
   subC: '0x00aa'
```

now PyYAML is not trying to convert them.

Thanks!