# Python yaml safe_load: How to keep the original order

Tags: python, yaml

I am using `yaml.safe_load` method to process a file, and I can see that the data that is being returned by that call is in a different order

This is my code:

```
    a=yam.safe_load('{"method1": "value1","method2": "value2"}' )
    print(a)
```

And this is the output

```
{'method2': 'value2', 'method1': 'value1'}
```

What can I do to keep the original order?

Comment: Python (<3.6) dictionary does not preserve order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how can you load YAML mappings as OrderedDicts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931/in-python-how-can-you-load-yaml-mappings-as-ordereddicts)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `round_trip_load` instead of `safe_load`:

```
from ruamel import yaml

data = yaml.round_trip_load('{"method1": "value1","method2": "value2"}')
for key in data:
    print(key)
```

According to the YAML specification the order of keys in mappings is not to be preserved, so this is what the backwards compatible `safe_load` does. Only the `round_trip_load` represents the mapping in an ordereddict subclass automatically to preserve the order (and comments etc).