# How to change mapping type in pyyaml?

Tags: python, pyyaml

I want to load some YAML data in a Python script, but instead of using regular `dict` for mapping, I would like to use my custom class (which keeps the insertion order and also merges keys/subdictionaries instead of overwriting them). I don't want to alter any other YAML types, only mapping. Browsing through the net, pyyaml documentation and SO I don't see any clear an generic solution - in almost all cases undocumented features of pyyaml are used (for example most of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931/in-python-how-can-you-load-yaml-mappings-as-ordereddicts)). Initially I was thinking about inheriting from `yaml.Loader` and reimplementing `construct_mapping()`, but it seems that it would also require to use some of pyyaml internals... But maybe it would "just work" when done like this:

```
# in my custom loader
def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
  mapping = yaml.Loader.construct_mapping(self, node, deep)
  # do my own stuff with mapping, changing it to my own type
  return mapping
```

?

Maybe I should just add my custom constructor and use `!!map` as the YAML tag which will be matched? Will this work that way, even though typically mapping has no explicit tag in YAML file?

Am I missing some obvious solution here, or maybe reimplementing `construct_mapping()` is the easiest approach?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this without non-officially documented features, e.g. because you fail to construct your mapping in a two step process. That is undocumented, but not doing so will certainly give you problems when using non-restricted YAML. Additionaly: 1) if things are on SO, you should consider them documented. 2) PyYAML is stable (read: barely maintained), so these "undocumented features" are extermely unlikely to change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how can you load YAML mappings as OrderedDicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931/in-python-how-can-you-load-yaml-mappings-as-ordereddicts)

Comment: @Anthon - the problem with solutions in the answer I linked is that I have absolutely no idea what is going on there, why particular functions are used (for example why `construct_pairs()` instead of `construct_mapping()` and what's `flatten_mapping()` doing actually) (; That's why I would prefer something more "straightforward", as there would be less guessing.

Comment: What is straighforward and what is not is of course relative. This is undocumented in the official sources and I think it is not straightforward in your sense of the that word. That means **you** cannot do it in the *straightforward* way that **you** want. Either study the PyYAML sources for a couple of days (as I did) to make doing this  straightforward, or accept that there is a straightforward solution (that you-understandably-don't fully grasp). If those solutions don't work, then come back here with a concrete question (and your not working source code).

Comment: @Anthon - would this be easier to do in ruamel.yaml than in pyyaml?

Comment: No, it would be harder (if you want to do it for the BaseLoader as well as for the RoundTripLoader). The type is hard-coded in the `constructed_mapping`  method PyYAML and the non-roundtrip loaders in ruamel.yaml (inherited from PyYAML) and in `construct_yaml_map` for the `RoundTripLoader`