# How to preserve the order of Key Value in YAML file using python (not alphabetical order)

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I have the python code below for generating (dumping) a YAML document to a file.

```
import yaml
import os
device_name = "NN41_R11"
ip = "10.110.11.11"
port = "2022"
def genyam():
    data  = {
         "testbed" : {
            "name"  : "boot_ios"},

        "devices"  :  {
            device_name  :  {
                "type"  : "IOS",
                "connections"  : {
                    "defaults" : {
                        "class"  :  "con.con",
                    "a"  :  {
                        "protocol" : "telnet",
                        "ip" : ip,
                        "port" : port,
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }

    with open('/tmp/testbed.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)`
```

which generates the following YAML file

```
devices:
  NN41_R11:
    connections:
      defaults:
        a:
          ip: 10.110.11.11
          port: '2022'
          protocol: telnet
        class: con.con
    type: IOS
testbed:
  name: boot_ios
```

Though the key value indentation is correct it's not generating in right order. I would like to have testbed first & then devices however it's opposite now. I am suspecting it's dumping in alphabetical order. `NN41_R11` is again a dictionary which contains `type & connections` (`type` & `connections` are generated at same level but need first `type:IOS` and under that `connections`). Looking for ordered dump basically

The generated YAML document should be like the following:

```
testbed:
    name: "boot-ios"
devices:
    NN41_R11:
        type: IOS
        connections:
            defaults:
                 class: 'con.con'
            a:
              protocol: telnet
              ip: 10.110.11.11
              port: 2022
```

Comment: You have two problems: first your `data` is a Python dict and that is not ordered. Even writing that dict has no guarantee that the keys are in a certain order. The second problem is that you use PyYAML which adheres to the YAML 1.1 spec and has no built in mechanism for dumping a dictionary like object with ordered keys as a mapping (without a tag). Question: do you have to use PyYAML for this or do you just want to generate a YAML document in a file from Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931/in-python-how-can-you-load-yaml-mappings-as-ordereddicts

Comment: @Anthon I want to generate the yaml file from python program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you look at ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), it is specifically designed to preserve order of keys when loading and dumping (i.e. round-tripping) YAML documents and can also easily be used to generate YAML documents with your specifics on the fly.

You'll have to somehow order your key-value pairs in your source, as although there is order in the Python source this is not preserved in the `dict` with name `data`. The `omap` type (i.e. `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap`) can be initialised with list of tuples, but I often find it easier to use step-by-step assignment.

To get double and single quotes around those strings that don't need it use the `dq` (i.e. `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString`) resp. `sq` (i.e. `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString`)

You can get rid of the quotes around the port by specifying it as an `int`.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap as omap
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString as dq
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString as sq

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4)

device_name = "NN41_R11"
ip = "10.110.11.11"
port = 2022

def genyam():
    # initialise omap with list of tuples that are key-value-pairs
    data = omap([
        ('testbed', omap([('name', dq('boot_ios'))])),
    ])
    # or add in the order you want them in the YAML document
    data['devices'] = devices = omap()
    devices[device_name] = name = omap()
    name['type'] = 'IOS'
    name['connections'] = connections = omap()
    connections['defaults'] = omap([('class', sq('con.con')),])
    connections['a'] = a = omap()
    a['protocol'] = 'telnet'
    a['ip'] = ip
    a['port'] = port
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)


genyam()
```

gives:

```
testbed:
    name: "boot_ios"
devices:
    NN41_R11:
        type: IOS
        connections:
            defaults:
                class: 'con.con'
            a:
                protocol: telnet
                ip: 10.110.11.11
                port: 2022
```

There is no way in `ruamel.yaml` (and even less so in PyYAML) to get different indents for different mappings as you have in your output (you have mostly four, but also five and two positions indent).

---

A completely different approach is to make a template for your YAML, and load and dump to make sure it is valid YAML (after filling out the template):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
testbed:
    name: "boot_ios"
devices:
    {device_name}:
        type: IOS
        connections:
            defaults:
                class: 'con.con'
            a:
                protocol: telnet
                ip: {ip}
                port: {port}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

def genyam2(device_name, ip, port):
    data = yaml.load(yaml_str.format(device_name=device_name, ip=ip, port=port))
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

genyam2(device_name = "NN41_R11", ip = "10.110.11.11", port = 2022)
```

This has the same output as the previous example, because on round-tripping order is preserved (and superfluous quotes as well if you specify `yaml.preseve_quotes = True`)