# How to get string objects instead of Unicode from YAML efficiently while using construct_mapping and add_constructor?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I'm using **pyyaml(Version: 5.1)** and **Python 2** to parse a **YAML** data body of an incoming POST API request.

The body of the incoming request contains some Unicode objects, along with some string objects.

The solution given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931/in-python-how-can-you-load-yaml-mappings-as-ordereddicts/21048064#21048064) is used to load the YAML mapping into an **OrderedDict**, where the **stream** refers to the incoming POST API request's **YAML** data body.

**But, I have to use the OrderedDict generated from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931/in-python-how-can-you-load-yaml-mappings-as-ordereddicts/21048064#21048064) with some library that only accepts string objects.**

**I can't change the library nor update it and I've to use Python 2.**

The current solution for this, which is being used is,

1. take the OrderedDict generated from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931/in-python-how-can-you-load-yaml-mappings-as-ordereddicts/21048064#21048064)
2. recursively parse it, converting any found occurrence of a Unicode
   object into a String object

The sample code for the same is as below,

```
def convert(data):
    if isinstance(data, unicode):
        return data.encode('utf-8')
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [convert(item) for item in data]
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        newData = {}
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            newData[convert(key)] = convert(value)
        return newData
     return data
```

Although this works, the solution is not efficient, as the complete OrderedDict is parsed after it is being created.

Is there a way, where the conversion of the data can be done before or during the generation of the OrderedDict, to avoid parsing it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a custom constructor that will always load YAML `!!str` scalars to Python unicode strings:

```py
import yaml
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver

def unicode_constructor(self, node):
  # this will always return a unicode string;
  # the default loader would convert it to ASCII-encoded str if possible.
  return self.construct_scalar(node)

yaml.add_constructor(BaseResolver.DEFAULT_SCALAR_TAG, unicode_constructor)
```

Afterwards, `yaml.load` will always return unicode strings.

(Code untested as I don't have a Python 2 installation)

Comment: The suggested code works fine, but I could not find good documentation about the usage of add_constructor. Can you please point towards that too?

Comment: The [official PyYAML documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) describes its general usage but does not go into much detail. To be frank, most things I know about how to use PyYAML come from reading its source code and knowing how the [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) describes the loading process of a file (covered in Chapter 3).